# How to select the element (div) below the selected one (grid style) in jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, keyboard-navigation

Select the div below the currently selected element.

Hi!

Okay, let say we have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="an-element selected"></div>
   <div class="another-one"></div>
   <div class="annnddd-onehere"></div>
   <div class="i-think"></div>
   <div class="you-got"></div>
   <div class="the-idea"></div>
</div>
```

the width of each div is fixed, but not the window size. On a big screen, all 6 elements are displayed on the same row. But on a smaller screen, the first row contain 4 elements and the second row contain 2 elements.

Now let's say the first element have the "selected" class. How can I add the "selected" class the the element below that one (if div does exists) ? (Obviously, the current .selected will be removed)

This is for a keyboard navigation system using the arrows.

Thanks for your time, as always ;)

**edit**

If the second element is selected, and the user press the down arrow, the sixth element will be affected.
If the third element is selected, and the user press the down arrow, nothing is going to happen because there's no div under that one.

I found a little aniamtion showing the "concept" here:
http://push-a-button.com/products/emucenter/

Comment: So on smaller screens you want to have 2 div having class `selected`?

Comment: you want to add class "selected" for every first div in a row ?????

Comment: dfsq, no the .selected class will be removed. sorry for the confusion. rynhe, I want to "jump" from the first one to the fifth one (because it's under)

Comment: So you want to be able to use ArrowDown/Up keys?

Comment: yeah, to go through the different div...

Comment: Take a look at another approach I came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `elementFromPoint` method. The idea is to test what element is located under the currently selected:

```
// testPos is the position under/over the selected element
var under = document.elementFromPoint(testPos.left, testPos.top);

// If the element has class block then we can highlight it
if (under && under.className == 'block') {
    selected[0].className = 'block';
    under.className = 'block selected';
}
```

#### Complete demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PMeNJ/1/

Comment: Interesting way of doing it. For fun I've tested doing it with "current eq minus eq per row" to calculate the block over the selected one. but your approach is simpler. Thank you for your help. +1 and accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

try `next()` and `addClass()`.

```
$('#container div.selected').next().addClass('selected');
```

however you if you have multiple selected div then you need to use loop to get each selected and addClass.

```
$('#container div.selected').each(function(){
   var $nextDiv=$(this).next();
   if(!$nextDiv.hasClass('selected'))
   {
        $nextDiv.addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: humm.. next() will select the next DOM element, which will be the one to the right. after the 4th one, it will go "down" for the fifth. I want to go directly from the first to the fifth element when the down arrow is pressed. (Only if there's two rows, if all elements fit on 1 row, it will do nothing... because it doesn'T exists...) - I'm not sure if I'm understandable haha

Answer (score 1):

The code will be like:

var diff = window.resolution - (#container div).width()*(#container div).length)

now count if the "diff" is the multiple of how many (#container div).width().

if it is two then it will be the 5th item...add class selected here.

if it is one then it will be the 6th item...add class selected here.

Comment: Thank you Rajiv007, I was going to do it that way, but I thought that maybe there's an "easier" way of doing that, but you confirmed me there's no other way. :) Vote up. (I'll accept the answer soon)